# vb.net read arraylist to excel column of cells

Tags: vb.net, excel, arraylist

I'm trying to read values from one excel file to arraylists, then use this information to fill another arraylist. what I tried doing was this

```
    For cellcount As Integer = 1 To buildList.Count
        oSheet.Range(1, cellcount).Value = buildList(cellcount-1)
        oSheet.Range(2, cellcount).Value = streamList(cellcount-1)
    Next
```

and I'm getting an error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

I can fill just a single cell by doing this

```
    oSheet.Range("A7").Value = buildList(2)
    oSheet.Range("B7").Value = streamList(2)
```

does anybody know a way to increment "A7" to A8, A9, A10, etc. same with B? or of a way to do this as if it were a 2D array? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To fill a range, you need a two-dimensional object, even if the range is 1-dimensional.

The range should also be between two cells.

Here is an example assuming we have an array `ArrayToAdd`, and a `cellcount` (as you had).

```
Dim exObArray(ArrayToAdd.length- 1, 0) As Double

'go through the list and add values to objects (2d array) 
For a As Integer = 0 To ArrayToAdd.length- 1 Step 1
    exObArray(a, 0) = ArrayToAdd(a)
Next

oSheet.Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 0), oSheet.Cells(1, cellcount)).value = exObArray
```

I'm not sure that I have the range right, but you get the idea. This one goes from  (1,0) to (1,cellcount)

Answer (score 0):

got it working by concatenating the number as a variable after the letter and incrementing it each time, as below

```
        For cellcount As Integer = 1 To buildList.Count

            oSheet.Range("A" & cellcount + 9).Value = buildList(cellcount - 1)
            oSheet.Range("B" & cellcount + 9).Value = streamList(cellcount - 1)

        Next
```

working as I wanted now.